# How can I get all the photo uploaded by user using Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read all of the Graph API document but nowhere mention to the photo uploaded by user.

I've found that for video uploaded by user, I can use: https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos/uploaded

But what about photo? Is it possible?

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English (cause English is not my native language :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you couldn't find it.

Anyway you need to query *two* tables to get what you want, the [`album`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/album/) and [`photo`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/) FQL tables:

```
SELECT pid 
FROM photo 
WHERE aid IN (
    SELECT aid 
    FROM album 
    WHERE owner=me()
)
```

You can get whatever you want from the `photo` table obviously. Also you may change `me()` to a user id.

I suppose that you need the `user_photos` or `friends_photos` permissions depending on your needs.

Comment: After "where aid in (...)" write "limit 100000", otherwise you will get only 100 photos from each album